# Background subtraction for object tracking

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, background-subtraction, matlab-cvst

i am working on object tracking. i want to use background subtraction. i have tried to find out papers on background subtraction but i am really confused to use which one. I have already done tracking using just gray scale subtraction and thresholding. but now i want to model the background and then use it for tracking. i do not know much about background modelling.So, if anyone can suggest me some techniques and good papers on background subtraction and modelling, i will be greatly thankful.

Comment: Gaussian mixture models for background modelling were once trendy.

Comment: Could you tell us about the papers you have read? I am interested in the subject and would welcome a primer on it.

Comment: You should provide some more information on the kind of images you're working with. Background subtraction is very specific to your domain.

Comment: OpenCV has a whole module for background subtraction that you can try with various algorithms.

Comment: I think that ViBe is a very good and easy to implement background modeling method. But it's patented, so be aware of that if you want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seminal paper on background modeling is [Adaptive background mixture models for real-time tracking](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/vsam/Publications/stauffer_cvpr98_track.pdf) by Stauffer and Grimson.

If you have Matlab and the Computer Vision System Toolbox, then you can try using `vision.ForegroundDetector`, which implements a version of their algorithm.